# Edit SurfaceTool vertices based on coordinates

Tags: godot

**Godot Version:** v4.0-alpha15

I have a terrain being generated using the [SurfaceTool](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_surfacetool.html) and the [MeshInstance3D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_meshinstance3d.html). I am also moving a purple decal acrossed the surface based on the 3D mouse position. Below is a screenshot of what this looks like.

[image]

I want to take the 3D mouse position and raise/lower the terrain on an action press. I found the [MeshDataTool](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_meshdatatool.html) but am not quite sure if this allows for that and also not completely sure how to convert the 3D mouse position to the corresponding vertices.

At this point I am sort of completely stuck as there's not a whole lot of documentation that I could find that helps.

I appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to figure this out using the [MeshDataTool](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_meshdatatool.html) as I mentioned in the original post.

I use the `Vector3::distance_to` method to get any vertex within 3 of the target position, then I use `MeshDataTool::set_vertex` in combination with Vector3 methods to add and subtract each of those vertex positions.

```
var target_position = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
var mdt = MeshDataTool.new()
var mesh = terrain_mesh_instance.mesh
mdt.create_from_surface(mesh, 0)
var points = get_vertex_id(mdt, target_position) 
for i in points:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shift"):
        mdt.set_vertex(i, mdt.get_vertex(i) + Vector3(0, 1 * delta,0))
    elif Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_ALT):
        var coords = mdt.get_vertex(i)
        coords.y = 0
        mdt.set_vertex(i, coords)
    else:
        mdt.set_vertex(i, mdt.get_vertex(i) + Vector3(0, -1 * delta,0))
# This fixes the normals so the shadows work properly
for face in mdt.get_face_count():
    var vertex = mdt.get_face_vertex(face, 0)
    var normal = mdt.get_face_normal(face)
    mdt.set_vertex_normal(vertex, normal)
mesh.clear_surfaces()
mdt.commit_to_surface(mesh)
```